# Create Custom Scroll Bar in Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

Is there any way to create a WearableRecyclerView with a custom scroll bar in Android Wear 2.0 like this?

[image]

Comment: Hi @kavie have you ever solved this one out? I want to create same effect like you and I am just digging into this... :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a curved layout for scrollable items in your wearable app check below link:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html#creating

use

val layoutManager = CurvedChildLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

PS: as for topic question, you dont need app:layout_box just use android:scrollbars="vertical" on your WearableRecyclerView

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/CurvedChildLayoutManager.html

Comment: It will show default scroll bar right?.How can i  create dotted scrollbar with different color using that?

Comment: use custom scroll bar.                                                                                                    Define these properties in listview                         android:scrollbarThumbVertical
android:scrollbarTrackVertical

Comment: Do u mean,Recycler List View with Circular  Scrollbar?

Comment: CurvedChildLayoutManager is deprecated now

Comment: Did you try WearableRecyclerView ?

Comment: yeah,I didn't get expected result.How can i add DotsPageIndicator in WearableRecyclerView ?

Comment: ,Im using WearableRecyclerView  with PagerSnapHelper

Comment: I think you have to create a scrollbar layout.  write your own logic to indicate scroll area based on current list position.

Comment: I have found same from this link https://www.thinksaas.cn/group/topic/822885/,I need to show vertically