# Parse different data through the activity in the same activity

Tags: java, android

I am building an E-Commerce App and I have an activity showing image slider, description and related items, and in image slider I have put an arrow to change the product on the arrow click I want to be in the same activity but data should be different.How should I do that need your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You should try doing it by urself in one of the many ways its possible to. Then we could provide some help with your idea or show you better solution. I think you are looking for `RecyclerView` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). It lets you show some similar views but with different data inside. Also as an item inside `RecyclerView` you can try `CardView`. 
Using only `RecyclerView` you can also use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084182/8713068
You can also search for a library that has everything you want inside already implemented. For example the first library that came out after i typed it in google : https://github.com/Ramotion/cardslider-android.